# Solaris x86: Non working keys on keyboard (<, >, #, |)

Tags: solaris, keyboard

I have a new installation of Solaris 10 10/09 on x86 hardware. The attached keyboard has a normal German layout. The system is configured accordingly by 'kbd -s'.

The generic keys (letter, number, umlaut) work fine. Unfortunately some keys like <kbd><</kbd>, <kbd>></kbd>,  <kbd>|</kbd>  or  <kbd>#</kbd> do not. They produce no output on the text console at all.

I tried PS/2 and USB keyboards. I cannot test it under X11 as it is currently not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to edit /boot/solaris/bootenv.rc ? 
Change the keyboard line to "setprop keyboard-layout 'German'".